# Asymptotic Solutions To Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been asked to find the asymptotic solution to a differential equation that was to be solved numerically using mathematica, however I don't really understand what an asymptotic solution really means.

I know what an asymptote is, but don't see it's importance or connection to the solution of a differential equation.

For reference, the differential equation I was asked to solve was $x'(t) = \sin(x + t)$, with initial value $x(0) = 0$. I found the solution (using mathematica) to be $x(t) = \pm 2 \arccos(\frac{-(-2 + t) \cos(t/2) + t \sin(t/2)}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{2 + (-2 + t)t}})$

A plot of this solution looks like this;

[image: Plot of Solutions]

Which makes me think the asymptotes are essentially flat lines (I will determine the value of m and c), but what is the relation to the solution here?

Why is this a meaningful quantity?

Thanks!

(my course notes do not mention them)

Comment: The equation satisfies the conditions of the theorem of existence and uniqueness, but you give two different solutions.

Comment: I don't see a derivative in your differential equation.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo. I have fixed it.

@JuliánAguirre I have not seen those theorems before

Comment: It is a differential equation, not a delay differential equation. The change $y=x+t$ transforms it into the equation $y'=\sin y+1$.

Comment: The solution found by Mathematica is wrong after the second zero of the solution. This is a consequence of using inverse trigonometrical functions and their different branches. If you want to plot the correct solution, use `NDSolve` instead of `DSolve`.

Comment: The correct solution should be $x(t)=2\tan^{-1}(t-1)-t+\frac{\pi}{2}$.